# How to Insert Overwrite Hive Table without failing with org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Can only write data to relations with a single path.?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, hive, apache-spark-sql

I have a Hive Table Which I want to overwrite use Insert Overwrite, Example Query below

```
spark.sql("INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE my_database.my_table VALUES (221221, 'DUMMY_Record_Pav', 21233, 'SPACE')")
```

```
--Show create Table
CREATE TABLE `my_database.my_table`(    
  `player_id` string,   
  `player_type` string,     
  `position_id` string,     
  `position_location` string)   
ROW FORMAT SERDE    
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe'     
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (  
  'path'='hdfs://path/hive/data/my_database.db/my_table')   
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT   
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetInputFormat'   
OUTPUTFORMAT    
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetOutputFormat'  
LOCATION    
  'hdfs://path/hive/data/my_database.db/my_table''  
TBLPROPERTIES ( 
 --Redacted
 )
```

That Spark Sql query is failing with below Error

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Can only write data to relations with a single path.;
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSourceAnalysis$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(DataSourceStrategy.scala:188)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSourceAnalysis$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(DataSourceStrategy.scala:134)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$$anonfun$resolveOperatorsDown$1$$anonfun$2.apply(AnalysisHelper.scala:108)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$$anonfun$resolveOperatorsDown$1$$anonfun$2.apply(AnalysisHelper.scala:108)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:70)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$$anonfun$resolveOperatorsDown$1.apply(AnalysisHelper.scala:107)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$$anonfun$resolveOperatorsDown$1.apply(AnalysisHelper.scala:106)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$.allowInvokingTransformsInAnalyzer(AnalysisHelper.scala:194)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$class.resolveOperatorsDown(AnalysisHelper.scala:106)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.resolveOperatorsDown(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$class.resolveOperators(AnalysisHelper.scala:73)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.resolveOperators(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSourceAnalysis.apply(DataSourceStrategy.scala:134)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSourceAnalysis.apply(DataSourceStrategy.scala:52)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:87)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:84)
  at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foldl(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:57)
  at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foldLeft(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:66)
  at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foldLeft(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:84)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:76)
  at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.execute(RuleExecutor.scala:76)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$analysis$Analyzer$$executeSameContext(Analyzer.scala:127)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.execute(Analyzer.scala:121)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$$anonfun$executeAndCheck$1.apply(Analyzer.scala:106)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$$anonfun$executeAndCheck$1.apply(Analyzer.scala:105)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$.markInAnalyzer(AnalysisHelper.scala:201)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.executeAndCheck(Analyzer.scala:105)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:57)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed(QueryExecution.scala:55)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertAnalyzed(QueryExecution.scala:47)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.ofRows(Dataset.scala:78)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sql(SparkSession.scala:651)
  ... 49 elided
```

I am able to overwrite to a similar table which doesn't have SerdeProperties like below:

```
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (  
  'path'='hdfs://path/hive/data/my_database.db/my_table')
```

Is there a way I can remove the SerdeProperties for a Table?

I tried setting the Path to '' like below but the Spark Sql failed with Empty Path Error.

`ALTER TABLE my_database.my_table SET SERDEPROPERTIES('path'='');`

Removing SerdeProperies will help the Spark SQL query to run.

Answer (score 0):

You could create intermediate table

```
Create table mytable2 () with ();

insert into mytable2 select * from mytable;

alter table mytable rename to mytable1;
alter table mytable2 rename to mytable;
```

Comment: Hey, Alex Yes I thought of that One but, How do I go about it with Partitioned Table?

Comment: You need to define mytable2 as partitioned.